# 59 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am new to iOS programming.So I am not getting how to fix this error. I am using Xcode 7.2.1.While building my app I am getting this
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition._transitionContext in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition._animationController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition._isActive in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition._percentComplete in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingAnimationController._coordinatorAnimations in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingAnimationController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingAnimationController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ECSlidingAnimationController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingAnimationController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingAnimationController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECSlidingAnimationController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingAnimationController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingAnimationController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingAnimationController._coordinatorCompletion in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingAnimationController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingAnimationController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingAnimationController._defaultTransitionDuration in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingAnimationController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingAnimationController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition._positiveLeftToRight in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition._slidingViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition._fullWidth in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition._currentPercentage in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingInteractiveTransition._coordinatorInteractionEnded in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingInteractiveTransition.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingSegue._skipSettingTopViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingSegue.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingSegue.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingSegue._isUnwinding in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingSegue.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingSegue.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ECSlidingSegue in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingSegue.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingSegue.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECSlidingSegue in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingSegue.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingSegue.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._gestureView in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._anchorRightRevealAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._anchorLeftRevealAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._anchorRightPeekAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._preserveRightPeekAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._anchorLeftPeekAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._preserveLeftPeekAmount in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._transitionInProgress in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._coordinatorAnimations in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._customAnchoredGestures in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._underRightViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._underLeftViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._topViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ECSlidingViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECSlidingViewController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._currentAnimationController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._defaultAnimationController in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._customAnchoredGesturesViewMap in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._currentTopViewPosition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._currentInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._defaultInteractiveTransition in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._coordinatorCompletion in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._defaultTransitionDuration in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._currentOperation in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._isInteractive in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._animationComplete in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._delegate in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._resetTapGesture in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._panGesture in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._topViewAnchoredGesture in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._currentAnimationPercentage in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._isAnimated in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._transitionWasCancelled in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._coordinatorInteractionEnded in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._underRightViewControllerStoryboardId in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._underLeftViewControllerStoryboardId in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ECSlidingViewController._topViewControllerStoryboardId in:
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Intermediates/iHealApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iHealApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ECSlidingViewController.o
    /Users/coders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iHealApp-ckstaumxwtiyvpgeursmlweqpdmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libECSlidingViewController.a(ECSlidingViewController.o)
ld: 59 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: There is some problem related to import

Comment: Yeah that I came to know. But don't know what is that . If u Please help me.

Comment: did you import m files?

Comment: No I didn't import .m files.

Comment: ECSlidingViewController is 3rd party right ?

Comment: This error may occur when you import it in cyclic order say if u import ECSlidingViewController.h in appdelegate and in other file you imported appdelgate and ECSlidingViewController.h

Comment: @Reshmi Majumder can you please explain what exactly you are trying to explain.

Comment: 1.  did u import ECSlidingViewController.h in app delegate?    2.  appdelegate.h and ECSlidingViewController.h in other viewcontroller

Comment: I have imported ECSlidingViewController.h file in my ViewController class.Not in AppDelegate.

Comment: I just want to ask you that are you importing ViewController.h and ECSlidingViewController.h in any other viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your compile sources in project target. There must be duplicate files, remove those and you are good to go.

> project Targer -> Build phases -> compile sources

Comment: I have checked but i didn't find any duplicate files.

Comment: Yes you have. check ECSlidingViewController files

Comment: I am checking those files only.But not getting anything

Comment: Then remove it completely, delete derived data, then add again

Comment: I have removed it completely and again added it.. But getting same error.

Comment: can u share some screnshots?